# Unable to Solve , Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to dispatch a login function from a component.
But this error on submit

> Warning: An unhandled error was caught from submitForm() Error:
> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a
> function component. This could happen for one of the following
> reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)

Here are the versions

```
 "react-dom": "^17.0.2",

 "react": "^17.0.2",
```

> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

I'm using only one app.

I have been using this approach in other projects similarly, but this time it is not working,
Please help me to eliminate this issue.
That is the related code.

```
export default function LoginForm() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch;
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin);
  const { error: loginError, loading: loginLoading, userInfo } = userLogin;

  const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false);

  const LoginSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.string().email('Email must be a valid email address').required('Email is required'),
    password: Yup.string().required('Password is required'),
  });

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      email: '',
      password: '',
    },
    validationSchema: LoginSchema,
    onSubmit: () => {
      dispatch(login(values.email, values.password));
    },
  });

  const { errors, touched, values, isSubmitting, handleSubmit, getFieldProps } = formik;

  const handleShowPassword = () => {
    setShowPassword((show) => !show);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userInfo) {
      navigate('/dashboard', { replace: true });
    }
  }, [navigate, userInfo]);
```

Comment: Make a codesandbox

Comment: If I console it `console.log(values.email, values.password));`  instead of dispatch. `dispatch(login(values.email, values.password));` this is printing the values, but not able to call the login function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're assigning the `useDispatch` function to `dispatch` const

```
const dispatch = useDispatch;
```

instead of calling the hook to get the actual dispatch function

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
```

That's why you're getting the error later when calling the dispatch.

Comment: OMg , that was a silly mistake by me , thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try useRef

```
const navigate = useRef(useNavigate());

......


useEffect(() => {
    if (userInfo) {
      navigate('/dashboard', { replace: true });
    }
  }, [navigate, userInfo]);
```